# Swizzling a single instance, not a class

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, categories, swizzling

I have a category on NSObject which supposed to so some stuff. When I call it on an object, I would like to override its dealloc method to do some cleanups.

I wanted to do it using method swizzling, but could not figure out how. The only examples I've found are on how to replace the method implementation for the entire class (in my case, it would override dealloc for ALL NSObjects - which I don't want to).

I want to override the dealloc method of specific instances of NSObject.

```
@interface NSObject(MyCategory)
-(void)test;
@end

@implementation NSObject(MyCategory)
-(void)newDealloc
{
  // do some cleanup here
  [self dealloc]; // call actual dealloc method
}
-(void)test
{
  IMP orig=[self methodForSelector:@selector(dealloc)];
  IMP repl=[self methodForSelector:@selector(newDealloc)];
  if (...)   // 'test' might be called several times, this replacement should happen only on the first call
  {
     method_exchangeImplementations(..., ...);
  }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't really do this since objects don't have their own method tables. Only classes have method tables and if you change those it will affect every object of that class. There is a straightforward way around this though: Changing the class of your object at runtime to a dynamically created subclass. This technique, also called isa-swizzling, is used by Apple to implement automatic KVO.

This is a powerful method and it has its uses. But for your case there is an easier method using associated objects. Basically you use `objc_setAssociatedObject` to associate another object to your first object which does the cleanup in its `dealloc`. You can find more details in [this blog post on Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/02/17/extending-nsdata-and-not-overriding-dealloc/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically, for each call - I allocate a new object (which I implement) and set it as the associated object and I do the cleanup inside its dealloc?

Comment: Exactly. Look at that blog post, it even has a nice category on `NSObject` that let's you register blocks to be called during dealloc of any object.

Answer (score 12):

Method selection is based on the *class* of an object instance, so method swizzling affects all instances of the same class - as you discovered.

But you can change the class of an instance, but you must be careful! Here is the outline, assume you have a class:

```
@instance MyPlainObject : NSObject

- (void) doSomething;

@end
```

Now if for just some of the instances of `MyPlainObject` you'd like to alter the behaviour of `doSomething` you first define a subclass:

```
@instance MyFancyObject: MyPlainObject

- (void) doSomething;

@end
```

Now you can clearly make instances of `MyFancyObject`, but what we need to do is take a *pre-existing* instance of `MyPlainObject` and make it into a `MyFancyObject` so we get the new behaviour. For that we can swizzle the class, add the following to `MyFancyObject`:

```
static Class myPlainObjectClass;
static Class myFancyObjectClass;

+ (void)initialize
{
   myPlainObjectClass = objc_getClass("MyPlainObject");
   myFancyObjectClass = objc_getClass("MyFancyObject");
}

+ (void)changeKind:(MyPlainObject *)control fancy:(BOOL)fancy
{
   object_setClass(control, fancy ? myFancyObjectClass : myPlainObjectClass);
}
```

Now for any *original* instance of `MyPlainClass` you can switch to behave as a `MyFancyClass`, and vice-versa:

```
MyPlainClass *mpc = [MyPlainClass new];

...

// masquerade as MyFancyClass
[MyFancyClass changeKind:mpc fancy:YES]

... // mpc behaves as a MyFancyClass

// revert to true nature
[MyFancyClass changeKind:mpc: fancy:NO];
```

(Some) of the caveats:

You can **only** do this if the subclass overrides or adds methods, and adds `static` (class) variables.

You also need a sub-class for ever class you wish to change the behaviour of, you can't have a single class which can change the behaviour of many different classes.

Comment: But in that case, I have to know in advance what would be the class of that instance. In my case, the object can be anything (even an object created by the SDK itself), so I can't assume I'll know the type.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the caveats! If that is needed go the associated object route. But it if you are targeting specific classes swizzling is a bit (subjective of course) simpler than associated objects and more general as you can override any method easily.

Comment: Even though I've used an associated object as my solution, I appreciate your answer. I do have a question about it: since it's only useful to override/add methods - what's the different between this and a category?

Comment: A category adds methods to all instances of a class. The above method changes the behaviour of a single instance of a class by making it into a subclass of that class (subject to the caveats).

Answer (score 1):

I made a swizzling API that also features instance specific swizzling. I think this is exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGMethodSwizzler

It works by creating a dynamic subclass for the specific instance that you're swizzling at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool to do this. https://github.com/623637646/SwiftHook

```swift
try hookDeallocBefore(object: obj) {
  // obj will be released.
}
```

Refer to this unit test.
https://github.com/623637646/SwiftHook/blob/9d2d85a64059617f8272d01ff59c10ede7305a48/SwiftHookTests/SwiftAPITests/HookSpecificInstanceTests.swift#L254