# How can I clone a NSCoding compliant object into a subclass of it?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscoder

I have a custom subclass of `NSPopUpButtonCell` so that I can overwrite its `drawBezelWithFrame:inView:` method.

Currently, I have to create a fresh instance using `initTextCell:pullsDown:` and then copy all its properties by hand. That's rather tedious and error-prone as I may be missing some properties.

I wonder if I can use `initWithCoder:` for this task instead. I imagine I should be able to file the data from the existing `NSPopUpButtonCell` instance into an `NSCoder` object, e.g. into `NSKeyedArchiver`, and then file that data back into my `NSPopUpButtonCell` subclass. But I can't figure out how to accomplish that.

Comment: How do you create the popup button, programmatically or XIB?

Comment: @Willeke From a Nib, and I alteady learned that I could solve that particular one more easily. Still, I like to learn if there is a way to clone any object in a subclass of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just used the wrong functions before. The solition is pretty straight-forward.

This code duplicates the properties of a NSPopUpButtonCell into a subclass of it, so that I can overwrite its draw... methods:

```
@interface MyPopup : NSPopUpButton
@end

@implementation MyPopup
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // Set up the archiver
        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
        NSKeyedArchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
        // Archive the cell's properties
        [self.cell encodeWithCoder:arch];
        [arch finishEncoding];
        // Set up the unarchiver
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *ua = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        // Create a subclass of the cell's class, using the same properties
        MyCell *newCell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithCoder:ua];
        // Assign the new subclass object as the NSButton's cell.
        self.cell = newCell;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Another, cleaner, way to use a custom NSButtonCell subclass is shown here: [Using full width of NSPopupButton for text, no arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396189/)

Answer (score 1):

If all your subclass does is override methods, i.e. it does not add additional fields, then you can swizzle the class of your original `NSPopupButtonCell`, or a copy of it, so it becomes and instance of your subclass.

Apple implements KVO using this technique, in that case using a dynamically generated subclass. If your case the subclass is static, making it a lot easier, the outline of the code is:

```
object_setClass(<an NSPopupButtonCell instance>,
                [<your subclass> class]);
```

If you can safely change the class on the original instance then this involves no object creation or copying at all.

Remember you can **only do this if the subclass changes behaviour only**.

For another explanation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504341/swizzling-a-single-instance-not-a-class/9504733#9504733).

HTH